# Pls suggest way to click on - Facebook sign up page- CREATE NEW ACCOUNT BUTTON- using selenium java ( Right click is not permitted)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden

Please suggest way to click on - Facebook sign up page- CREATE NEW ACCOUNT BUTTON- using selenium java ( Right click is not permitted)
I tried using this code-- https://www.facebook.com/--

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_2_1a"));       
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;     
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"#u_0_2_1a"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `ID` attribute which can change. Hence its throwing no such element. Please use the xpath as below:

```
//form//a[@role='button'][contains(.,'Create New Account')]
```

I just tested it. it works. Below should be your code.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form//a[@role='button'][contains(.,'Create New Account')]"));
```